# Архивирование устаревающих данных БД

Tags: python, база-данных, django, postgresql

Есть проект на Django, использующий базу данных.
Задача заключается в том, чтобы удалять из БД устаревшие объекты с помощью специального скрипта.
Но удаленные объекты не хочется удалять безвозвратно, а хочется их где-то сохранять. Например, в какой-то архивной базе данных.
Возможным решением проблемы будет хранение двух баз данных - одна для сервера, другая для архива. Тогда перед удалением объекта из серверной бд, необходимо копировать объекты в архивную. Как это реализовывается? Или для решения подобных проблем используются в принципе другие методы?

Comment: [не оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27713026/5741205)

Comment: У вас заголовок противоречит тексту вопроса. Объекты БД - это таблицы, столбцы, вью, триггеры, индексы, хранимые процедуры и т. п. А данные БД - это то, что хранится в таблицах. Уточните, что из этого вам нужно?

Comment: @Dmitry я хочу удалять старые объекты джанговских моделей. Например есть модель "Новости", нужно удалить объект класса новости, которому больше месяца. Как его удалить понятно. А как его класть в архивную бд не очень. Или вообще может другие способы есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для вас не принципиален размер вашей базы данных и вы хотите архивировать записи в определенных таблицах для удобства, например для того что бы не выводить их в ваших темплейтах, то можете добавить к архивируемым моделям флаг is_archive. По моему мнению можно использовать следующую структуру:

```
from django.db import models


class ActualManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_archive=False)


class ArchiveModel(models.Model):
    is_archive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = models.Manager()
    actual = ActualManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# модель поддерживающая архивирование
class Model1(ArchiveModel):
    pass

# модель поддерживающая архивирование
class Model2(ArchiveModel):
    pass
```

Обратите внимание что порядок в котором определяются менеджеры важен.

Если вам нужны только актуальные экземпляры, вы просто вызываете Model1.actual.all()

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from main.models import Model1


class ArchiveTestCase(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        Model1.objects.create()
        Model1.objects.create()
        Model1.objects.create(is_archive=True)

        self.assertEqual(Model1.actual.count(), 2)
```